# How to find empty folders using smart folder

Tags: smart-folders

I need to find all empty folders using smart folder.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just select options in the image below and you will get all empty folders.

[image]

Comment: Didn't know it was that easy, thank you so much !

Comment: is it possible to find folders with files like .DS_Store, Icon? using this method?

Comment: This does not work me, it results in countless false positives.